# Как пройтись по строке и вставить символ перед нужным элементом? (python)

Tags: python

Есть вот такая строка: 'XXX34X65236X36'
Нужно получить вот такую 'X-X-X-34X-65236X-36'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print ('XXX34X65236X36'.replace('X','X-'))
```

Comment: Блин, так просто было :) Спасибо большое !

Comment: Когда то и для меня это было не просто)) Слава, Гуглу!